# Android emulator weird graphic get stuck on screen

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-tools

I am using the android emulator on Linux Kubuntu 20.04.

Whenever I hit some keyboard sequence (I am not sure what it is but it probably has to do with ctrl+alt+right), I get a weird graphic with 3 teal circles and a line. Once that graphic displayed, I can no get rid of it, and it even persists when I changed to a different virtual desktops or minimize the emulator.

What is this graphic and how do I prevent it / get rid of it?[image]

Comment: idk why someone downvoted this; I have the same problem on arch linux-lts after a clean install(many times already). I'd like to know why it doesn't go away. Today I noticed that only happens after I hit ctrl tab. This is definitely broken from the emulator side and it should be fixed!

Comment: press Ctrl button and see the result.

Comment: just pressing ctrl doesnt fix; the screen gets stuck with this multitouch gesture and I already tried to press the entire keyboard; I know a few years ago I discovered a combination of keys to press to fix this, but I can't remember know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hit the zoom button (twice?) for a temporarily fix.

For a permanent fix enable (or disable I cant remember) Settings > General > Send Keyboard Shortcuts to Virtual Device.

Comment: Had the same problem as @betoharres (comment to question). I'm on Gnome, and the trigger was likely my ctrl+alt(+shift)+j/k shortcut to move to other workspace. The emulator gets stuck in the mode *over all workspaces, with the controls being visible & covering all workspaces* and steals focus even from the emulator toolbar, so no way to click the zoom button.
Only the permanent fix worked.

Answer (score 0):

This graphic is the multi-touch functionality of the emulator. It's presented to you - assuming you are using the default emulator from android studio - for a mac user by holding the command button, and for windows/linux I think it is alt button while left clicking with your mouse.

You can use this functionality for actions such as pinching or any other functionality for which you'd require multiple inputs.

Not sure in your case why it doesn't go away though, as it works fine for me.

---

In my personal experience, I usually trigger this when I'm trying to take a screenshot with shortcuts, so to prevent this just click on something other than the emulator before taking one